# AJAX not getting response because of page refresh

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, httprequest, razor-pages

I am implementing a feature which allows a user to upload a file which is processed  server-side with some information returned as a JsonResult. This worked fine with another AJAX request where I sent only strings. It seems like because `FormData` is being sent it causes a page refresh, which for me means I never reach the response part of my code. I would appreciate it a lot if someone dug me out of this hole, thanks!

#### MyPage.cshtml

```
<input id="readFromFile" type="file"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="ResultsFromFile()">Get Results</button>
<script>
function ResultsFromFile() {
        var temp = $("#readFromFile")[0].files;
        if (temp.length > 0) {
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (var x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
                    data.append("file" + x, temp[x]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'AlexaIndex?handler=GetResultsFromFile',
                    headers: { "XSRF-TOKEN": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log('result is ' + response);
                        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
                        PopulateTable(jsonObj);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
</script>
```

#### MyPage.cshtml.cs

```
public JsonResult OnPostGetResultsFromFile()
{
    foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", file.FileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyTo(stream);
        }
        var urlList = ReadFileOfUrls(path);
        ModelState.Clear();
        var results = _alexaExtractorService.GetAwisResults(urlList);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
        return new JsonResult(json);
    }
    return new JsonResult("FINITO MINITO");
}
```

Comment: This is because the submit button actually submits the result to the serve, meaning it does the action defined in the form tag on the resource defined, you need to suppress the default behaviour, you can do this using the [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) method

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks, I tried this way and it worked too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's happening is because your button is wrapped in a `form` element, and all `button` elements with `type="submit"` will post the form to the server.  Prevent the submit button from actually submitting by preventing that default action with `e.preventDefault();`

```
<input id="readFromFile" type="file"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="ResultsFromFile(event)">Get Results</button>
<script>
function ResultsFromFile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var temp = $("#readFromFile")[0].files;
        if (temp.length > 0) {
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (var x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
                    data.append("file" + x, temp[x]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'AlexaIndex?handler=GetResultsFromFile',
                    headers: { "XSRF-TOKEN": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log('result is ' + response);
                        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
                        PopulateTable(jsonObj);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I added a note as to what you intended here, feel free to improve that.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense.

Comment: Perfect, this is the solution! thanks @CoOl and MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 2):

Change the button type to `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="ResultsFromFile()">Get Results</button>
```